# Can someone point out my syntax error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I believe that I have a syntax error somewhere in my script, could someone point it out?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Challenge: Daisy chain</title>
    </head>
        <body>

    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script>
    for (i=0;i<12;i++)
    {
    $('<img>')
    .attr('src', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/English_Daisy_(Bellis_Perennis).jpg')
    .attr('width','100')
    .attr('alt', 'Daisy chain')
    .appendTo(document.body);
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The JavaScript error console is usually very specific. What does it say?

Comment: @tadman he is creating new img tag dynamically.. its correct.

Comment: @APaul Never used that notation before. Interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what syntac error you are seeing at your side.. But I would have made some changes

1. Move the script inside head
2. add the code inside a function that will be called on page load

> ```
>  <!DOCTYPE html>
>         <html>
>             <head>
>                 <meta charset="utf-8">
>                 <title>Challenge: Daisy chain</title>
>               <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
>             <script>
>           $(function() {
>             for (i=0;i<12;i++)
>             {
>             $('<img>')
>             .attr('src', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/29/English_Daisy_(Bellis_Perennis).jpg')
>             .attr('width','100')
>             .attr('alt', 'Daisy chain')
>             .appendTo(document.body);
>             }
>           });
>             </script>
>             </head>
>                 <body>
>         </body>
>         </html>
> ```